# Does Visual Studio have a capability like Emacs registers?

Tags: visual-studio, emacs, editor

Registers are a feature of emacs that I make a lot of use of. For those not familiar, you highlight some text, and then ask emacs to place it in a numbered register (0-9). Then as you're going along you can ask emacs to insert the text in the given register into your code.

Basically I can save a chunk of text on the fly and then insert it into a buffer at a later time. The content of the register dies when the session dies.

Question is, does Visual Studio have a similar feature?

Comment: The registers are not numbered 0-9, they are named with a signle character. So there is a register "a", a register "b" etc as well.

Comment: I am more interested in saving the position in register to jump back and forth between files, anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl-shift-V will allow you to cycle through the last few things you copied or cut.

Good luck.

Comment: So that's like "Ctl-Y" followed by "Alt-Y" in emacs. Not quite what I'm looking for, but still good to know. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also drag text onto the Toolbox and later drag it back. Then, of course, there are Code Snippets, macros, etc.